# Can't edit Security Roles from Non-Default Business Unit

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

When "customising the system" in Dynamics 2013, I cannot see any roles outside of the default business unit (even if I move my "System, Customiser user" to the business unit in question. I have tried a solution and the defauilt solution. How do you see all roles in all business units to customise the roles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Security roles are exportable with a solution file, but only those from a root (top-level or 'default') business unit.

This is because you cannot export a Business Unit in a Solution. Therefore, you cannot export Security Roles for a Business Unit that is not in the same Solution.

If you want to export a Security Role, you will have to have it in the root solution. When it is imported in the destination organisation it will propagate to all the business units (because it is in the root)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use **Security Roles** from the SETTINGS > Administration option and not to try and customise them from within a solution. Editing roles from the solution doesn't show them all.

Oddity.